# PowerShell Where-Object not working as expected with square brackets [ ]

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I am trying to use PowerShell to filter out result (rows) based on keyword match "[X]" (literally an X surrounded by square brackets)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {Get-WindowsFeature} | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*[X]*"}
```

The result is larger than expected. I'm picking up results that contain [, ], and X in any order or combination. As long as all the characters are on the line. I'm using -like which does not use Regex. I thought that was the job of -match. Removing the wildcard doesn't help.

Before anyone asks, why am I not filtering on the 'installstate' property. This is an older PowerShell module running remotely and doesn't seem to return that property at all, hence I have no choice but to look for an explicit "[X]"
Thanks

Comment: `-like` does _wildcard pattern comparisons_, and `[X]` is a special sequence - change to ```-like '*`[X`]*'``` to look for literal string `[X]`

Comment: Thanks, literally what I just did before seeing your comment. But still doesn't work. This one returns no results at all. A google reveals there are various quirks with PowerShell and square brackets.

Comment: Please note that I'm using _single-quotes_ - if you're using double-quotes, you need to double-escape: ```-like "*``[X``]*"```

Comment: Did notice. And just tried with double quotes for the hell of it, no results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two questions here:

#### How do I filter on strings containing `[X]`

As mentioned in the comments, wildcard patterns in PowerShell use `[]` for a special purpose (describing character ranges), so you need to escape the brackets with a backtick:

```
PS ~> 'This string contains [X] somewhere' -like '*`[X`]*'
True
```

**Beware** that the backtick is also the escape character used in *expandable strings*, so if you use double-quotes, you need to double-escape the brackets:

```
PS ~> 'This string contains [X] somewhere' -like "*``[X``]*"
True
```

Alternatively, go for something simpler like good old `String.Contains()`:

```
'This string contains [X] somewhere'.Contains('[X]')
```

... or ask PowerShell to escape your reference string for you:

```
'This string contains [X] somewhere' -like "*$([WildcardPattern]::Escape('[X]'))*"
```

#### How do I filter output from `Get-WindowsFeature`

The reason it doesn't work is that the nice tree-like indentation and the `[X]`/`[ ]` indicators are *not actually part of the output object* - it's imposed by PowerShell's formatting subsystem and only appears when the output it listed as a formatted table.

Since the `[X]` signifies that the component is "Installed", the equivalent query against the underlying data is really:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WindowsFeature
} | Where-Object {$_.InstallState -eq "Installed"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. The installation status property associated with this 'older' Get-WindowsFeature command turned out to be "**Installed**" instead of "InstallState". You can see it if you pipe out to Format-List.

Comment: @NadimAJ You're welcome! I only tested on Server 2016, you're saying you needed to do `... |Where-Object {$_.Installed -eq 'Installed'}` instead? If you let me know which OS version, I'll add it to the answer (you can also [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66135561/edit)) :-)

Comment: OS version was 2008. For 2012 and above the property appears to be InstallState